# Injecting a function into a subclass

Tags: c++, overloading

Is it possible to do such things in `C++14`. I have a base class as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

class AbstractElement;
class ConcreteElement;
class SuperConcreteElement;

class B
{
public:
    void bar(AbstractElement*)
    {
        std::cout << "Abstract element" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(ConcreteElement*)
    {
        std::cout << "Concrete element" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(SuperConcreteElement*)
    {
        std::cout << "Super concrete element" << std::endl;
    }
};

class AbstractElement
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class ConcreteElement : public AbstractElement
{
private:
    B _b;
public:
    void foo()
    {
        _b.bar(this);  //1
    }
};

class SuperConcreteElement : public AbstractElement
{
private:
    B _b;
public:
    void foo()
    {
        _b.bar(this); //2
    }
};

int main()
{
    AbstractElement *e = new ConcreteElement();
    e -> foo(); //Prints Concrete element
}
```

As you can see at `//1` and `//2`, the function's body is completely similar. But I can't quite move it into a base class because of depending on the static type of `this`. In spite of that fact, I wouldn't like to write absolutely the same code every time I need to add one more subclass of `AbstractElement`. So, I need some kind of mechanism which provides us with the facility to inject code into a function.

As long as marcos are not very desirable solution, I'd like to ask about some tricks that can be done in `C++14` for solving such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
#include <iostream>

class AbstractElement;
class ConcreteElement;
class SuperConcreteElement;

class B
{
public:
    void bar(AbstractElement*)
    {
        std::cout << "Abstract element" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(ConcreteElement*)
    {
        std::cout << "Concrete element" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(SuperConcreteElement*)
    {
        std::cout << "Super concrete element" << std::endl;
    }
};

class AbstractElement
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class CRTPAbstractElement : public AbstractElement
{
    B _b;
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        T* t = dynamic_cast<T *>(this);
        _b.bar(t);
    }
};

class ConcreteElement : public CRTPAbstractElement<ConcreteElement>
{
};

class SuperConcreteElement : public CRTPAbstractElement<SuperConcreteElement>
{
};

int main()
{
    AbstractElement *e = new ConcreteElement();
    e -> foo(); //Prints Concrete element
}
```

By adding an intermediate CRTP class we are able to cast a pointer to the base class to a pointer to the derived class. Thus solving the issue of code duplication.

Comment: Cool, actually I suspected that templates would be helpful here, but didn't know how to use it.